# Test bench file for integer types

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to simulate the following VHDL module in XIlinx ISE 14.7, but the generated VHDL test bench file assumes that all input and output ports are of type std_logic and std_logic_vector.

```
package newtype is
type row_t is array(0 to 2) of integer;
end newtype;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.newtype.all;

entity mymodule is
port (indata : in  row_t;
        sum : out integer);
end mymodule;

architecture Behavioral of mymodule is
begin
process (indata)
begin
    sum <= indata(0) + indata(1) + indata(2);
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I modified the generated code replacing std_logic_vector with my types, but this time it gives me syntax errors.
Could you please tell me what is the right way write a text bench file when you work with integer types?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use work.newtype.all;

ENTITY mymodule_test IS
END mymodule_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mymodule_test IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT mymodule
    PORT(
         indata : IN  row_t;
         sum : OUT  integer
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal indata : row_t := (0,0,0);

    --Outputs
   signal sum : integer;
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 

  constant <clock>_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: mymodule PORT MAP (
          indata => indata,
          sum => sum
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   <clock>_process :process
   begin
        <clock> <= '0';
        wait for <clock>_period/2;
        <clock> <= '1';
        wait for <clock>_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      wait for <clock>_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: You're working along the right lines. The auto-generator for testbenches makes garbage which you have to fix. Not only the types as you have done, but you also have to fill in the <template> bits as Martin Zabel says. Finally, this testbench will only work for behavioural simulation. You rarely need post-synthesis or post-P&R simulation, but if you do, you'll need a wrapper for the gate level component that simply translates port types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't posted the syntax errors you encountered. But, if I create a new project in Xilix ISE 14.7 and just add the above code, I get these syntax errors:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -
>   "mymodule_test.vhdl"
>   Line 28: Syntax error near "<". ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -
>   "mymodule_test.vhdl"
>   Line 39: Syntax error near "<". ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -
>   "mymodule_test.vhdl"
>   Line 41: Syntax error near "<". ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -
>   "mymodule_test.vhdl"
>   Line 54: Syntax error near "<".

All these lines contain the indentifier or prefix `<clock>` which is a template parameter of Xilinx's testbench generator. If this, generator detects a clock within the design you have selected in the wizard (here `mymodule`), then `<clock>` is replaced by the actual name of the clock signal. The testbench generator didn't found a clock signal within your design, so it just inserted the plain template code. These syntax errors are not related to the usage of the type `integer` within the testbench.

Your design does not depend on a clock signal, so you can safely remove all the testbench code associated with the clock signal:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use work.newtype.all;

ENTITY mymodule_test IS
END mymodule_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mymodule_test IS 
    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    COMPONENT mymodule
    PORT(
         indata : IN  row_t;
         sum : OUT  integer
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   --Inputs
   signal indata : row_t := (0,0,0);

    --Outputs
   signal sum : integer;

BEGIN
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: mymodule PORT MAP (
          indata => indata,
          sum => sum
        );

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;
END;
```